# Hacked Gmail-reset pass-fowarding to Icloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, mail.app, gmail

Srry for my bad english.

Hi, i need to ask for help. Iff someone hacked my gmail, but i reset pass(log out all devices) after 2 hours(and add sms verification), but i didnt notice that is IMAP-turned on. Can someone still recieve emails from my gmail to his Icloud? or after reset pass(log out all devices+ add second verification) he coulnt recieved it ? Thank a lot for help.

he sync gmail with his apple mail/icloud and he could recieve all my email to his mail/icloud and storage it. And after i reset my gmail pass if there some chance that he could still recieving my emails or he lost sync with his icloud to storage it. ( i dont understand exactly ho working imap between gmail and apple mail/icloud ..changed gmail pass reseting imap to sending emails to apple mail/icloud or ? there is still sync?) Thank a lot

Comment: This seems to be more a Gmail/Google question than something related to Apple products. What exactly do you mean by getting mail from Gmail to iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

iCloud (or iCloud Mail) itself can't access mail accounts on other providers via IMAP (or any other means). But I see at least two options how somebody with temporary access to your Gmail account can try to put a tap on your emails:

- By adding your Gmail account as an additional account to whatever mail application he uses. This only works while your Gmail password doesn't get changed (so you should be safe here)
- By setting up a mail forwarding rule in Gmail which forwards (copies) all your incoming mail to another email address. To verify and disable, please look inside Gmail (don't know the details and we are not a Gmail support site)